# Is there a way to have a Integer object with a changing value that is referenced by multiple names?

Tags: java, wrapper

I know that in c++ that you could do pointers to an wrapper Integer object but it seems that in java that the wrapper class will not reflect the change across multiple references as it just copies the value into a new wrapper. Like:

```
Integer s = 0;
Integer j = s;
s = 2;
```

I mean I could possibly use some class or data structure but I am worried that it will take to much space as there will be many of these objects. Any thoughts on a space efficient implementation of a object that has a dynamic integer referenced by various names across my program. Should I just implement a struct(c++) like class for its storage?

Comment: The first question i have is why you would want to do this in the first place.

Comment: Not `Integer`.  In Java the `Integer` class is immutable.  You could make your own `MyInt` class pretty easily though.

Comment: It allows for me to have a reference in the data structure of the highest value from that TreeNode down  on a tree. Otherwise, I would have to change the Highvalue int on every node above it if it is higher.

Comment: If you do that, and "Highvalue" is a key, your `Tree` will become unsorted and useless.

Comment: you could think about using a static variable..

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to understand why the code you provided is not doing what you think.

```
Integer s = 0;
Integer j = s;
s = 2;
```

Is the same as:

```
Integer s = Integer.valueOf(0);
Integer j = s;
s = Integer.valueOf(2);
```

You did not mutate the value of `s`, you pointed it to a different object.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have a Integer object with a changing value

No. `Integer` is immutable.

> that is referenced by multiple names?

Irrelevant given the above.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the `Integer` class is immutable. The [`MutableInt`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/mutable/MutableInt.html) class in the Apache Commons Lang library will do what you want:

```
    MutableInt s = new MutableInt(0);
    MutableInt j = s;
    s.setValue(5);

    System.out.println(s.intValue()); // 5
    System.out.println(j.intValue()); // 5
```